# Unable to find a specification for SimpeAuth (cocoapods)

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to use SimpleAuth pod.
My Podfile is

`pod 'SimpleAuth'`

I have changed the working directory of my terminal to the directory where my xcode project is present. Then I did

`pod install`

I got this message

```
Analyzing dependencies

[!] Unable to find a specification for `SimpleAuth`.
```

I tried searching for some possible solutions on google.

I got one solution as trying this

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
pod setup
pod install
```

I tried this. The first line executed.
Then, when I tried `pod setup`, I got this message

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!]The master repo is not a git repo
```

I got a solution for this asking me to try

```
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git ~/.cocoapods/repos/master
```

But that also gave an error

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___strlcpy_chk
  Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I even tried some other pods like SAMCache, Mantle etc. but same error every time.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

A few weeks ago we changed the folder structure of the main Specs repo, so older versions no longer work. Please update your version of CocoaPods.

Comment: I tried `gem update cocoapods` and `pod update` but I am still getting the same error